# Correctly starting up a Chrome session

Tags: java, selenium, windows-7, selenium-chromedriver

I have some java code working with Selenium.  Inside the static{} I set the DOWNLOAD_DIR.  The rest is done later on.

```
public static final String DOWNLOAD_DIR = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
...
...
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadDir);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
ChromeDriver newDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

this works fine when I run Selenium manually but when it runs in bamboo at night it gets this message
***The driver executable does not exist: /opt/app/bamboo/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/TEST-PRVPTLWC-JOB1/Packager/C:\eclipse\selenium-drivers\chromedriver.exe***

Chrome is already running.  I am creating a new driver to do some side work.  Not sure why I am getting that error but I thought I could specify the exact binary integrating the following from stack overflow:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "<Path to binary>");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

I think this will work but I am not sure how to get .  Remember, this will run on two different machines, one Windows and the other some Unix variation (bamboo) so I can't hard code the path.  I would like to be able to find the path to the binary I am currently running.  I do have access to the driver via getDriver() but when I looked at all the methods I did not see anything to show the binary location.  There is a capabilities option but I looked at the current driver's capabilities there is also nothing specifying a binary path.

Any idea how to get the binary?  Other people set up the testng environment so not sure I have access to that.

Thanks

p.s., the platform at my desk is Windows 7.  I am using Java with Eclipse and Selenium.  Bamboo I believe is a form of unix/linux.

Answer (score 0):

We need to set the location of chromdriver to launch chrome browser.

You can pass location of chromedriver through system property

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/path/to/chromedriver.exe");
```

You can pass same property as command line argument

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver.exe MyClass
```